# How do I turn off touch gestures in OS X even when no touchpad is detected?

Tags: macos, mac, touchpad, touchscreen, gestures

I have a delicate problem. I use a large multi-touch screen from PQ Labs with a Mac Mini. It is used in an exhibition where I run an application i fullscreen mode. However, since there is a touch gesture built in to OS X to exit fullscreen mode (pinch with all fingers) user can accidentally exit the app to the desktop. The problem is that one can not access the settings for gestures in System Preferences if the Mac hasn't detected a touch device such as a touch pad. In my case the PQ Labs screen has it's own drivers so it isn't detected as a touch device by OS X and hence I can not deactivate gestures. Is there a way to solve this with a script on startup or something?

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't have a trackpad active, you may need to borrow an Apple trackpad simply to change the setting in System Preferences.  If not, this might work:

```
defaults write com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad TrackpadFourFingerPinchGesture -int 0
```

Setting this value to 0 ***should*** disable the setting. Again, I'm not sure if this will work with your touchscreen

Here are some other values to try:

- Disable tap to click

  ```
  defaults write com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad Clicking -bool false
  ```
- Tap with two fingers to emulate right click

  ```
  defaults write com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad TrackpadRightClick -bool true
  ```
- Enable three finger tap (look up)

  ```
  defaults write com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad TrackpadThreeFingerTapGesture -int 2
  ```
- Disable three finger drag

  ```
  defaults write com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad TrackpadThreeFingerDrag -bool false
  ```
- Zoom in or out

  ```
  defaults write com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad TrackpadPinch -bool true
  ```
- Smart zoom, double-tap with two fingers

  ```
  defaults write com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad TrackpadTwoFingerDoubleTapGesture -bool true
  ```
- Rotate

  ```
  defaults write com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad TrackpadRotate -bool true
  ```
- Notification Center

  ```
  defaults write com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad TrackpadTwoFingerFromRightEdgeSwipeGesture -int 3
  ```
- Swipe between pages with two fingers

  ```
  defaults write NSGlobalDomain AppleEnableSwipeNavigateWithScrolls -bool true
  ```
- Swipe between full-screen apps

  ```
  defaults write com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad TrackpadThreeFingerHorizSwipeGesture -int 2
  ```
- Enable other multi-finger gestures

  ```
  defaults write com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad TrackpadThreeFingerVertSwipeGesture -int 2
  defaults write com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad TrackpadFourFingerVertSwipeGesture -int 2
  defaults write com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad TrackpadFourFingerHorizSwipeGesture -int 2
  defaults write com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad TrackpadFiveFingerPinchGesture -int 2
  ```